# How can I configure my apple watch to always make and answer calls via the embedded eSim (not via iPhone)?

Tags: apple-watch

I have a 6th generation Apple Watch with eSim support, data plan activated on my eSim.

1. I can answer phone calls on my watch when I'm close to my iPhone - the call is made from the iPhone but through the Apple Watch speakers.
2. I can answer phone calls on my watch when I'm very far away from my iPhone - the call is made from the watch via the embedded eSim and data plan.
3. I **cannot** however answer calls with my watch when my watch is somewhat close but not close enough to my iPhone, the calls get dropped, failed, sometimes my watch doesn't even ring.

I'm really looking from 3) from all of the above because that is *the* typical use case for me:

- my Phone is on my desk
- my watch is on my wrist and I am wandering in my house

Does this have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple Watch does not activate the cellular service unless it is disconnected from the phone. This is because the cellular service takes more than acceptable battery power.

Therefore, there is no way to receive a call directly to the watch when the watch believes it's connected to the phone, because the watch is disconnected from the cellular network.

For outgoing calls, there does not appear to be a way to disconnect from the phone, from the watch, without also disabling cellular service (as Airplane mode does).

---

If your watch can't maintain a connection with your phone on Bluetooth it should hop onto your Wi-Fi network. Do you ever see the Wi-Fi indicator in control center if you're in your house but far from your phone?

Comment: You are right with the battery power, I disconnected WiFi and Bluetooth on my watch for a quick test and battery went down to 10% in a few hours.
Regarding WiFi, when I'm far away from my phone (i.e. garage or frontyard), WiFi signal might get lost, which is probably the reason why I'm having the problems described.
Your answer is nonetheless much more understandable and clear than what I got from Apple representatives, much appreciated!